# Algebraizing topology and analysis via condensed mathematics

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, soft-question, condensed-mathematics

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427309/condensed-mathematics-and-analysis?noredirect=1#comment9265839_4427309) on Mathematics Stackexchange, but one of the users suggested that I ask this question at MathOverflow.

I've just come across a Twitter thread by [Laurent Fargues](https://mobile.twitter.com/laurent_fargues/status/1407319288076251152) explaining a work by Dustin Clausen & Peter Scholze under the name condensed mathematics and how condensed mathematics can *algebrize* topology and analysis. I find it somewhat surprising (or hard to believe) that you can do such a thing. So my question is can condensed mathematics completely *algebrize* topology and analysis, or can it only algebrize some analytic object close to algebraic geometry? Can we reprove theorem and inequalities in analysis such as [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), and so on using condensed mathematics?

Comment: You're absolutely right.  There's no way condensed math can "completely algebrize" topology and analysis, nor even close.  I prefer to say that what it's good for is _mixing_ topology and analysis with algebra.  It does this by recasting topology and certain aspects of analysis in a way which is more friendly to algebra.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I guess it is probably very useful for algebraists, but not much of an interest for an analyst then?

Comment: Reading that Twitter thread made me wonder if future math textbooks will have emojis scattered throughout them. After all, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki_dangerous_bend_symbol is a kind of proto-emoji...

Comment: The title of Dustin Clausen's talk **New foundations for functional analysis** (a video is, e.g., here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKC0fciQkfU) is not as modest as the comment of the user Dustin above.